# how to calculate offsetwidth manually a particular tag in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need calculate offsetwidth from some tag width and height... How can i calculate offsetwidth a particular tag, I know `<div>` Height = 563px, width=763px,  I using `<p>` with some content, p tag left 110px, top 123px, within div tag... how can find offsetwidth value calculate manually...

Already it have javascritp element.offsetWidth but I need calculate manually offsetwidth.. how can I do this?

```
<div height="563px", width="763px">
<p style="left:110px;top:123px">some text<p>
<div>
```

I need calculate offsetwidth... can anyone help with examples...?

Answer (score 0):

Offsetwidth of an element can be calculated as

`element.offsetWidth`

In your case if you have id of the div

`document.getElementById('divId').offsetWidth`

P.S. :- *[offsetWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.offsetWidth) is a measurement which includes the element borders, the element horizontal padding, the element vertical scrollbar (if present, if rendered) and the element CSS width*